# Javascript not executing change in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have an MVC and am using JS and JQuery.

I have VS2008 using dev server.

I have added some javascript to a JS file "SearchControl.js" and ran it fine.

Then I made a change and for some reason it was not hitting
a brakpoint I put in.

So I put a breakpoint on some older code and it breaks
but brings up a new file in VS called "SearchControl.js [dynamic]"
which does not contain my new code.

Is the JS file being cached??
I tried to close VS and tried again same thing.
What is going on??

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

You could try renaming your js file from SearchControl.js to something like SearchControl-1.0.js to force the browser to fetch a new version of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is this JS file an embedded assembly?  If so, make sure you have recompiled and dropped the assembly containing the JS file into the GAC.  Reset IIS.